# Golang path to image and uploading getting mixed results

Tags: go

I have successfully been able to upload images to my ImageStore account however I have had to hardcode each file path . My issue is that my images reside outside of my GoPath are there any way that I can get the actual directory to my images without hardcoding it ? For instance

**GoPath** = "/Users/IH/Documents/go"

**Actual Image Path** = "/Users/IH/Documents/pictures/horse_PNG2538.png"

**Path I'm getting** = "/Users/IH/Documents/go/src"

I need to get the correct path of an image because user's will be able to Upload their images and obviously they are all going to have different paths to their images . This is the code I have

```
myfile, handler, err := r.FormFile("uploadImage")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)

    return
}
defer myfile.Close()


pwd, err := os.Getwd()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
fmt.Println(pwd)

file,err := os.Open(pwd + handler.Filename)

defer file.Close()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("err opening file: %s", err)
}
```

The pwd gives me the path **/Users/IH/Documents/go/src** which offcourse gives me an error because the image is not found there . If I for instance hard code the correct image address then it uploads such as

```
file,err := os.Open("/Users/IH/Documents/pictures/horse_PNG2538.png")
```

then the image gets uploaded . Again this image is coming from this directory **/Users/IH/Documents/pictures/** how can I spot that directory on image upload without hardcoding it ? any suggestions would be great

Comment: If you don't want to hard-code your path prefix, then it must be configurable. You can use either way you want, like an environment variable, a configuration file, a user input, whatever suits your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

The "os/user" package allows you to determine the directory of the current user like so:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/user"
)

func main() {
    usr, err := user.Current()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(usr.HomeDir)
}
```